# How add tag <span> between <a></a> in ClinkPaget yii

Tags: html, yii, pagination

I have templates of pagionation:

```
<ul class="container">
          <li><a href="#"><span class="w-icons-pagPrev"></span></a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><span class="help">1</span></a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><span class="help">2</span></a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><span class="help">3</span></a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><span class="help">4</span></a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><span class="help">5</span></a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><span class="help">6</span></a></li>
          <li><div class="help">...</div></li>
          <li><a href="#"><span class="help">41</span></a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><span class="help">42</span></a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><span class="w-icons-pagNext"></span></a></li>
      </ul>
```

I need add  tag span and class to  this span. How I can dot this? In CMenu are two options :

1. linkLabelWrapper
2. linkLabelWrapperHtmlOptions

But in CLinkPager they are not.

I tried override CLinkPager:

```
class NewsPager extends CLinkPager
{

    protected function createPageButton($label,$page,$class,$hidden,$selected)
    {

     if($hidden || $selected)
         $class.=' '.($hidden ? $this->hiddenPageCssClass : $this->selectedPageCssClass);
     return '<li class="'.$class.'">'.CHtml::link("<span  class='help'>".$label."</span>",$this->createPageUrl($page)).'</li>';
    }
}

It work, but also I need add various class to first and last button. How I can do that?
```

Comment: To he? Dot this??? They They? Please re-edit your code with proper spelling so we can understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way

```
$this->widget('CLinkPager', array(
    'currentPage'=>$pages->getCurrentPage(),
    'itemCount'=>$item_count,
    'pageSize'=>$page_size,
    'maxButtonCount'=>6,
    'nextPageLabel'=>'<span class="w-icons-pagNext"></span>',
    'header'=>'',
));
```

or this

```
'pager'=>array(         
         ....
         ....
        'nextPageLabel'=>'<span class="w-icons-pagNext"></span>',
),
```

Comment: A lot of thank! What as for  <li><div class="help">...</div></li>? how add it?

Comment: You've tried `'nextPageLabel'=>'<div class="help">...</div>',` ? What's happen ?

Comment: Oh,I explained wrong. I need somethink like that [link](http://joxi.ru/BA0pgD8hEdzzAy)

Comment: I'm sorry. i don't know this . I think is not possible with Yii Pager or however I don't know how to do this